# get host ipv6 with PHP

Tags: php, ipv6, googlebot

I want to verify the Googlebot using the following function. But this function does not support ipv6

[php document for gethostbyaddr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php)

One solution was mentioned in the link below, but it does not work :
[A solution that does not work](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php#26641)

I want to get the domain name and then match it with the following statements:

> google.com
>
> googlebot.com

In the following link, you can see examples of Google IP:

https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-the-ip-address-of-google-818153

Do you know a solution to this issue?

Comment: If the User-Agent claims to be googlebot, check if their IP is in the ranges specified on that page. You don't need to do a query.

Comment: @Sammitch Google has stated in the document that this ranges may change at any time.
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/verifying-googlebot

Answer (score 2):

If the client sent the request using IPv4, then you'll get the IPv4 address. If your server is serving IPV6  they sent the request using IPv6, you'll get the IPv6 address.

A client will send a request to your server using only one protocol.

Comment: So if it sends with ipv6, how do I get its domain?

Comment: do you accept ipv6 on your server

Comment: I have a shared host. How should I understand this?
Isn't it true that some users are IPV6 and others are IPV4?
Why should it be closed on a server?

Comment: @maja this answer your question, you should really read more how it all works.